# SSL Common Name Wildcard

Tags: ssl, https, wildcard

I looked through the other questions and didn't really see anything specific to this.

My boss bought a QNAP NAS server for our office and up until now it's been great to use. Up until I needed to start testing out some eCommerce site.

I can't get my server to accept my OpenSSL certificate with *.redefine.dynalias.com

The structure of the workspace is that I have virtual hosts set up so that a directory 'www.site1.com' will be accessed as 'www.site1.com.redefine.dynalias.com'. Simple enough.

https://redefine.dynalias.com, if you look at the information, it states it still is a wrong site, with an unknown identity. What could I possibly be doing wrong? Even adding an exception causes an error that prevents me from testing the eCommerce site.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A wildcard in a certificate only matches one level.

a cert issued to *.redefine.dynalias.com will not be a valid certificate for redefine.dynalias.com

a cert issued to *.redefine.dynalias.com will not be a valid certificate for x.x.redefine.dynalias.com